# Move contents of an array into a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

My array has lib1 ver1 lib2 ver2 lib3 ver3

I want to assign the contents of the array to a hash so that my hash has lib1 as the key and ver1 as the corresponding value something like 
lib1=>ver1 lib2=>ver2..So when I print the contents using foreach something like

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
        print("Key is $key and value is $hash{$key}\n");
```

It should print 
key is lib1 and value is ver1
key is lib2 and value is ver2

Comment: `m/\S+=\S+/\s+` is not a valid regex.

Comment: Also `lib1=ver1 lib2=ver2 lib3=ver3 ` is not valid Perl code.

Comment: Is "something" a string, or an array... or a file... or something else?

Comment: I am actually getting this lib1=ver1 lib2=ver2 lib3=ver3 after concatenating a couple of variables in a tcl script. I am reading this line as it is into perl and tryign to parse it..So until the array part, it is just working fine..My array has the contents mentioned above

Comment: &GetOptions("lib_version=s" => \$opt_lib_version); This part of the code is reading that variable form tcsh to perl ..

Comment: `@array = (lib1 ver1 lib2 ver2 lib3 ver3)` is not valid Perl code. If you want to list the contents of an array, perhaps you should use `Data::Dumper` output. "Something like" is not going to be a popular description around here.

Comment: No that is not a part of the code..That is the currently what I have in @array.. You can assume I ran the above code and my array currently has lib1 ver1 lib2 ver2 lib3 ver3 as it's contents I mean

Comment: That is what you think you have in the array. Do `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@array;`

Comment: I rephrased my question to make it more understandable

Comment: Well, your old code should work, so its not a matter of understanding, it is a matter of you thinking you have something you do not have, or not using it the way you should.

Comment: I do have the above variables in the array..So do you think %hash = @array; would do it?

Comment: No, you *think* you have the above *strings* in your array, but my guess is that you do NOT have those strings in your array, which is why your assignment `%foo = @bar` does not work, when it SHOULD work.

Comment: Which brings me back to my request: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@array; `

Comment: For debugging I removed other contents and so when I add the line you mentioned to my perl script I get this                        `$VAR1 = [
          "lib1",
          "ver1"
        ];`

Comment: If you have that in your array, you can safely assign it to a hash and get the expected result.

Comment: Ok I must have screwed something ..Will check again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original post, if you have

```
my $lib_version = 'lib1=ver1 lib2=ver2 lib3=ver3'
```

Then splitting it like this

```
my @array = split /=/, $lib_version
```

won't split it as you want it. You will end up with

```
@array = ('lib1', 'ver1 lib2', 'ver2 lib3', 'ver3')
```

because you are splitting only on the equals `=` signs.

To split *both* on `=` and whitespace you could write

```
my @array = split /[\s=]/, $lib_version
```

or, better

```
my @array = $lib_version =~ /[^=\s]+/g
```

After that, `my %hash = @array` will work fine